# Using Angular to pull data from MongoDB based on form input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, mongodb, drop-down-menu

I am new to Angular and Mongo, and am hoping to use Angular js to pull data from a Mongo database to populate a div on a single-page website I'm building. What data is pulled will depend on what option a user selects in a dropdown option on a form. There are a Lot of options out there for Angular, and I was hoping that someone with more experience with it could point me in the right direction. Below are the relevant bits of my code:

```
<body ng-app="">
  <div id='ad'> </div><!-- to be populated with data from MongoDB -->
<select id='climateZone' ng-model="zone" >
  <option value="z3">3</option>
  <option value="z4">4</option>
  <option value="z5">5</option>
  <option value="z6">6</option>
  <option value="z7">7</option>
  <option value="z8">8</option>
  <option value="z9">9</option>
  <option value="z10">10</option>
</select>
 <button id='Go'><h2>Go!</h2></button>
```

I want it so that when a user selects one of these options, and presses the 'go' button, the 'ad' div will be populated with option-specific information from the database.

I hope that's all clear; any help is appreciated!

Comment: Time to look through the angular api at available event directives like `ng-click`, `'ng-change` etc. And the `$http` ajax api. There are also lots of tutorials around to help get you going. Questions like this are just a  bit too broad for this site. You are expected to try to resolve the basic issue(s) yourself and we help tweak code that isn't working

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you can't make HTTP request directly to MongoDB. Instead you need a server-side implementation that communicates with the database for you. If you are using Node for the back-end you can take a look on Mongoose: http://mongoosejs.com/

Mongoose is one of the many libs for MongoDB, you define you models, make queries, post data, and so on. Let's say I want to get the data based on a parameter. At first you need a model for your data:

```
var Cat = mongoose.model('Cat', { name: String });
```

Then you can start operating on top of the DB connection. The example bellow should bring you all cats named "Toddy":

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myDB');

Cat.find({name: 'Toddy'}, function (err, result) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.log(result);
});
```

That said, you can use the ngChange and ngModel directives to put the value of the combo on a variable and react properly when it changes, like so:

```
<select id='climateZone' ng-model="zone" ng-change="loadData()">
    <option value="z3">3</option>
    <option value="z4">4</option>
    <option value="z5">5</option>
    <option value="z6">6</option>
    <option value="z7">7</option>
    <option value="z8">8</option>
    <option value="z9">9</option>
    <option value="z10">10</option>
</select>
```

Being both "zone" and "loadData()" members of your $scope.